# Ограничить файловые операции PHP в cPanel

Tags: php, apache, безопасность

Необходимо ограничить папку, в которой может производить операции PHP код (в данном случае у одного сервера несколько владельцев).

Доступа к `httpd.conf` нет. Можно редактировать `.htaccess`, но злоумышленник может его перезаписать другим `.htaccess`.
Можно также редактировать `php.ini`.

Смотрел в сторону `suPHP` и встроенного `safe_mode`, но первый не обновляется около 15 лет, а второй был удалён. Есть ли ещё альтернативы, или единственный выход - "убрать всех конкурентов"?

**EDIT:** оказывается, на моём хостинге установлен lsphp. Можно ли воспользоваться его функциями для данных целей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена с помощью `RewriteRule` и специально написанного файла `proxy.php`, который устанавливал `open_basedir`, а затем через `require` подключал запрошенный файл. Таким образом, на подключенный файл никак не реагирует `.htaccess`.

Метод кривой, но хотя бы так. Возникается ещё проблема с `Content-Type`, который нужно создавать самостоятельно на основе расширений файлов. Спасибо svogal, [подсказавшему](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php#87856), как это сделать.